# In a TextFormField in flutter user enters a url or website link to save it to firebase database and the link should be opened with browser

Tags: forms, flutter, url, browser, textformfield

In a TextFormField in flutter  I want to  enter a url or website link to save it to firebase database and the link should be opened with browser ,i.e it should be clickable  before saving and saving it to firebase database.

Hece it should open the website or link with borwser etc.

How to achieve  this functionality in flutter

I have used   url_launcher: plugin  and imported  import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

my code is as follows

```
 child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value){
                          if(value.isEmpty){
                            return "Please write the Company Website of production";
                          }else {
                            website = value;
                          }
                        },

                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        autofocus: false,
                       // controller: _controller,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: ' Company Website ',
                          hintText: 'Enter the Company Website',
                          prefixIcon: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (await canLaunch("url")) {
                                await launch("url");
                              }
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.open_in_browser),
                          ),
                        ),
                        maxLength: 15,
                      )
```

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below code this will help you

```
             TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
              autofocus: false,
              controller: textEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: ' Company Website ',
                hintText: 'Enter the Company Website',
                prefixIcon: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if(textEditingController.text.toString() == null || textEditingController.text.toString() == ""){
                      print("null data");
                    }else{
                      print(textEditingController.text.toString());
                      if (await canLaunch("https://" + textEditingController.text.toString())) {
                        await launch("https://" + textEditingController.text.toString());
                      } else {
                        throw 'Could not launch ${textEditingController.text.toString()}';
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.open_in_browser),
                ),
              ),
              maxLength: 15,
            ),,
```

Comment: Sorry to ask you before implementing your code , but will this code  open the user  entered website or link  in a browser  i.e opens a website or link ?

Comment: Yes You can try this Just add proper site link @srk2k14

Comment: Yes Please @srk2k14

Comment: Thank you I am seeing that it is just printing the website link or url entered , but on click on the icon it should open the url too, which is not happening . please fix it.

Comment: Okay @srk2k14 just a min

Comment: hi @srk2k14 I edited my answer please check this answer, and if this worked for you please check marked it as true. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226389/discussion-between-shubham-narkhede-and-srk2k14).

Comment: Thank you , this has finally fixed my issue . Be with me for my others queries on stack pls.

Comment: Shubham Narkhede  please  answer to my query regarding viewing pdf here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395772/how-to-open-or-view-the-pdf-using-download-url-after-downloading-from-firebase-s